# Open the file chooser in an Android app using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Task: Upload an image which the user can choose from the device.

How can I open the [file chooser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_dialog) window on a button press in an Android app using Kotlin?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your activity, add the button click to add an intent:

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener {

    val intent = Intent()
            .setType("*/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 111)
}
```

Set a custom requestCode, I set `111`.

Add the `onActivityResult` in your activity to catch the result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedFile = data?.data // The URI with the location of the file
    }
}
```

Now `selectedFile` will contain the location of what they selected.

Comment: @Derek,How I can put exact location example "Android/data/package"

Comment: @engmms do you mean the file location of your application to store data?

Comment: @Derek,yes..the file location of your application to store data

Comment: @engmms it would look something like this `activity.filesDir.toString()`

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with folder instead of File ? 
In order to let the user select a folder path, not a file's.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in a PDF reader inside of a Fragment.

My code (without defining the correct directory to choose my file):

```
val selectedFile = data?.data // The URI with the location of the file <p>
pdfView.fromUri(selectedFile).load() // Show the selected file

// Fragment view
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val intent = Intent()
            .setType("*/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 111)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sat, container, false)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the correct directory to choose my file"*? The location the file dialog shows when it opens? Or something else? Can you elaborate?