# Kotlin Open file on button click

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. Can someone please tell me how to open a file on click of a button? Is there some command like:

```
Button.setOnAction {
File.Open(*//specified file path*)  
        }
```

I am using **Kotlin for Java development** and not for andriod. I have a **.fxml** file where I have defined this button and I need to define the above feature in a kotlin (.kt) file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a JavaFX question, depending on your platform requirements you should look at the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program

Comment: This question is related to what? Android?

Comment: @zsmb13 yes, it is a JavaFX related question but, the feature that I want should be defined in a Kotlin (.kt) file. I have to make this change in an already existing project.

Comment: @user5954246 Not related to Android.

Comment: You can use the code that solves this in Java with minimal changes in Kotlin.

Comment: this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444264/how-do-i-write-to-a-file-in-kotlin

Answer (score 1):

In your activity

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener {

    val intent = Intent()
            .setType("*/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 111)

}
```

still in your activity, insert this to catch the result

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedFile = data?.data //The uri with the location of the file
    }
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701868/9589162)

Comment: I think you answer is more related to Kotlin for Android because I am getting some errors when I use this code. Really sorry that I did not mention that the feature that I am looking for is not for Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this selectedFile path (@Rizkita answer) to read a text file, in onActivityResultfunction add something like this (Kotlin):

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedFile = data?.data //The uri with the location of the file

            // Get the File path from the Uri

            println(selectedFile?.lastPathSegment)
            val path = selectedFile?.lastPathSegment.toString().removePrefix("raw:")
            println(path)
            text_reader.setText(getTextContent(path))
        }
    }


fun getTextContent(pathFilename: String): String {

    val fileobj = File( pathFilename )

    if (!fileobj.exists()) {

        println("Path does not exist")

    } else {

        println("Path to read exist")
    }

    println("Path to the file:")
    println(pathFilename)

    if (fileobj.exists() && fileobj.canRead()) {

        var ins: InputStream = fileobj.inputStream()
        var content = ins.readBytes().toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
        return content

    }else{

        return "Some error, Not found the File, or app has not permissions: " + pathFilename
    }
}
```

> Note that in my example text_reader is just the id of a TextView object in the .xml layout file.