# Kotlin button file picker exception Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently learning Kotlin for Android development, for the moment I try do a file picker button to upload a csv file with different functionalities
I have done a script with the help of topics on the subject ([Open the file chooser in an Android app using Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697630/open-the-file-chooser-in-an-android-app-using-kotlin))

First, I just try to first put a button to open the file chooser component. However when I click on it, the app crashes.

At first, I thought there was a problem with the default extended class `ComponentActivity`, so I created a special class extended `Activity()` to manage the file choser component correctly.

I got the exception : `FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: com.example.MyProject, PID: 20702                                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`

Here is my code :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContent {
                 MyProjectTheme {
                      Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                             ) 
                     {
                      MyApp()
                     }
         }
       }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val fileLoader =  FileLoading();

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) { 
            Button(onClick = {
                fileLoader.openFileChooser()
            }) {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.load_button), fontSize = 24.sp)

            }
        }   
}

class FileLoading(): Activity() {

    fun openFileChooser() {
        val intent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                    intent.addCategory (Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a file"),
            111,
        )

        @Override
        fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val selectedFile = data?.data
              }
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe I should extends Activity instead of ComponentActivity ? But I am not sure on the impact on the rest of the application (I am used to only work with ComponentActivity for the moment).

I also saw a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVfRbnOLRGA) which explains to use ActivityMainBinding but I am fear to be not experienced enough to fully take in it hands

Is it possible help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Delete `FileLoading`. Only create a subclass of `Activity` when you intend to start it with `startActivity()` or something based upon it. **NEVER** create an instance of a subclass of `Activity` directly, as you are doing with `val fileLoader =  FileLoading();`.

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#activity_result) and [this Medium post](https://fvilarino.medium.com/using-activity-result-contracts-in-jetpack-compose-14b179fb87de), among other resources for using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()`, which is the Compose solution for your use case.

Comment: Thanks you, it helps me ! I think I get confused with myself, your links clarified a lot the activity result process